# Expect Script - For Loop - How to use more than 1 variable

Tags: for-loop, expect

How can I use more than 1 variable in expect script "for loop"? Please help.
Thanks in advance.

With one variable:

```
for {set i 1} {$i < 256} {incr i 1} {

}
```

How can 2 or 3 variables, say init , condition, increment of **i**, **j**, **k** ?
comma, semicolon is not working.

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that expect is an extension of Tcl. [Documentation of Tcl](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm) is available.

The syntax of [for](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/for.htm) is:

> **for** *start test next body*

"start" and "next" are both evaluated as scripts. "test" is an [expr](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm)ession

You can do:

```
for {set i 1; set j 10; set k "x"} {$i < 5 && $j > 0} {incr i; incr j -2; append k x} {
    puts "$i\t$j\t$k"
}
```

outputs

```
1   10  x
2   8   xx
3   6   xxx
4   4   xxxx
```

This is equivalent to the following, so use whatever is most readable.

```
set i 1
set j 10
set k "x"

while {$i < 5 && $j > 0} {
    puts "$i\t$j\t$k"

    incr i
    incr j -2
    append k x
}
```

In fact, you can make liberal use of newlines in a for command too

```
for {
    set i 1
    set j 10
    set k "x"
} {
    $i < 5 && $j > 0 
} {
    incr i
    incr j -2
    append k x
} {
    puts "$i\t$j\t$k"
}
```